# How to quickly group multiple features of data from a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say this is my original data:

```
data = {'library_id': ['A123', 'A456','B123', 'A123', 'A123', 'B123', 'A456'],
     'school': ['A1','A', 'B', 'A', 'A2', 'B', 'A'],
     'charge ($)': [5.0, 10.0, 3.0, 2.5, 1.0, 4.0, 2.5], 
     'check_in_month': [12, 3, 4, 5, 4, 9, 5]}
library =pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I am trying to get this outcome:

[image]

And this is my code to get the outcome:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(library.library_id.value_counts())

school_list = []
for i in df.index:
    school_list.append(library[library.library_id == i].school.unique())
df['school'] = school_list
df
```

My question is how I can avoid using lists (i.e. school_list = []) to get the same outcome. Because when I have large data, using lists to append data to a data frame is super time-consuming. Is there any other faster way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```py
result = library.groupby("library_id").agg({"library_id": "size", "school": "unique"})
```

to get

```
            library_id       school
library_id
A123                 3  [A1, A, A2]
A456                 2          [A]
B123                 2          [B]
```

We group by the `library_id` and then `agg`regrate it over the group `size` and the `unique` entries.

If you don't want `library_id` appearing on top of the index, you can write `result.index.name = None` since it is the name of the index of the `result`.